# Change less (pager) default options

Tags: ubuntu, less, pager

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04. My default pager(set using update-alternatives, not $PAGER) is less. The problem is, when I use ri(Ruby documentation tool) with the '-f ansi' mode, less shows the escape sequences(such as 'ESC[36m') instead of displaying the text in color. I can force it to show colors by manually piping the output to less with the -R option, for example:

```
ri -f ansi String | less -R
```

However, I'd like this to be the default option when less is used as a pager.

Note: I'm aware that more and most show colors by default, but I use less because of the vi-like key bindings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the answer somewhere else. I needed to use `lesskey` to set up less's options:

```
$ lesskey -
#env
LESS = -R
```

Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>

did the trick. I'm still not sure why less ignores $LESS though.

Comment: Aha! the options in `~/.less` (which is what `lesskey` writes) override those in the environment. So you must have had a `.less` file containing `LESS=-r` before.

Answer (score 5):

Set the `LESS` environment variable to a space-separated list of your favorite options.

Comment: Didn't work, less totally ignores $LESS. I'm guessing this is an Ubuntu-specific issue, since many other shell variables are ignored, including $PAGER and $EDITOR.

Comment: `less` definitely takes `$LESS` into account, on Ubuntu 10.04 like everywhere else. And `$PAGER` and `$EDITOR` work too. It sounds like you're not setting the environment variables properly. How did you do it?

Comment: I tried this: "export LESS='-R'; ri -f ansi String | less"

However, less does use other environment variables correctly, such as the ones mentioned here: http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/topic/2403/color-man-pages/

Comment: @imgx64: It Works For Me™, and I don't see how it could not work. Hmmm... What is the output of the two commands `type less` and `env | grep LESS`?

Comment: "less is /usr/bin/less" and "
LESS=-R 
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s 
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s 
"

Answer (score 1):

The most likely issue is that you didn't export the less variable.

```
LESS="FRX"
ls -l | less
<not colorized>

export LESS="FRX"
ls -l | less
<colorized>
```

You could, for example, create a file called '/etc/profile.d/less.sh', with just 'export LESS="FRX"' in it, and your less configuration will be available system-wide.

Comment: Yer no fun, slim.  ..what's wrong with pointing out a bit of necromancy?