# How to turn off word-wrap in less

Tags: linux, command-line, less

Short version:
How can I make the `less` utility in Linux not wrap lines?

Long version:
Often I need to view huge CSV files using less with hundreds of columns.  I frequently only care about the first couple columns.  However, word wrap causes one line to become several lines even on wide-screen monitors.

Answer (score 735, accepted):

*Note: For the key binding, see the second part.*

In `less`, it's called line folding rather than line wrapping. 
To set it not to fold, use the `-S` option:

```
-S, --chop-long-lines
```

> Causes lines longer than the screen width to be chopped rather than folded.  That is, the portion of a long line that  does  not fit in the screen width is not shown.  The default is to fold long lines; that is, display the remainder on the next line.
>
> — [less(1)](http://man.cx/less)

---

Alternatively, as mentioned in the below comment, if you already opened the file, you can toggle the mode by typing `-S` (and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> for some implementations).

After disabling line folding, you can scroll sideways with the arrow keys.

Comment: ... and toggle inside `less` with the same keys (`-`, then `Shift-S`).

Comment: Now that I disabled "line chopping", how do I scroll horizontally?

Comment: @becko use the right and left arrow keys.

Comment: For GNU less, -S does not work in combination with -r

Answer (score 48):

If you want to stop wrapping permanently, cast these spells:

```
echo "#env" >> ~/.lesskey
echo "LESS = -S" >> ~/.lesskey
lesskey
```

Comment: It's far more straightforward, IMO, to simply set the LESS variable in your shell RC. I'm not sure if the LESS variable is supported as widely as the very old lesskey mechanism, but if so, I'd recommend using it.

Comment: Yes, using the env var LESS seems to be a bit more straight forward: `LESS=-S less logfile.txt`

Comment: Or even using an alias: `alias less='less -S'`

Comment: I'm missing instructions here for undoing these spells...

Comment: @einpoklum The shell commands simply add two lines to the end of the file `.lesskey` in your home directory.  They are easy to remove with a text editor.

Comment: @tripleee running lesskey also modifies ~/.less. I had to remove ~/.lesskey and ~/.less in order to revert the changes.

Comment: [Change less (pager) default options](http://superuser.com/q/174286/113004)

Answer (score 17):

Don't know if less has a option for that, but I use the [most](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_%28Unix%29) command which does that by default (and allows scrolling left/right to view it)

Comment: `most` seems like a nice program, but I can't believe it doesn't have a shortcut to go to the end of the file. The convenient `less` command "G" asks for line number and doesn't recognize "$". While it seems like it mimics `less` in certain ways, I don't understand why the author didn't make it fully compatible.

Comment: @haridsv Pretty sure the `End` key works in less, to go to the end of the buffer; At least in my `gnome-terminal`

Comment: less also allows scrolling left/right.  Works even when the file wasn't opened with `-S` option.

Comment: use `B` to go to file **b**ottom and `T` to go to file **t**op

Answer (score 9):

To setup git so it always does not wrap:

```
git config --global core.pager 'less -S'
```