# How can I make Unix Less wrap long columns?

Tags: unix, less

I need to view a large tab delimited file using less. There is a column with ~200 characters which I am not interested in seeing but that column pushes all other columns to right making the viewing hard. Is there a way to prevent less from showing more than the tab width in a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'cut' to delete that column and redirect the output to less.

For eg if its the first column that you don't want to see

```
cut -f 1 --complement $FILENAME | less
```

If you have a delimiter other than tab, you can specify that using '-d;

```
cut -d ',' -f 1 --complement $FILENAME | less
```

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
less -S
```

does the trick. See also [the answers here](https://superuser.com/q/272818/122798)