# git diff filter for minimized files

Tags: git

I have a minimized JSON file in my git tree. It is a bunch of data on a single line, without spaces.

Diffs for this file are not very useful, any change in the data, of course, results in the whole line being changed.

I'd like to be able to *optionally* tell git to diff not the file itself, but output of a pretty-printer (like `python -mjson.tool` or `jq .`) for that file.

Right now I'm using this command:

`diff -u <(git show HEAD:file.json | jq .) <(jq . < file.json)`

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

I would set up a git [textconv](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Textconv) filter for the affected file(s).

In .gitattributes, set the diff tool:

```
*.json diff=json
```

And in .git/config:

```
[diff "json"]
    textconv = "cat $1 | json_pp"
```

`json_pp` is present in the Git for Windows distribution, and I had more luck with this than with `jq`.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution that I usually follow is to have a pretty printed source code, and minify into an untracked file while building. this is pretty good as:

- source will be always readable.
- there will not be any unwanted changes to the source files

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've done for going over a collection of `.json` files and finding which file(s) differ:

```
for f in `git ls-files *.json`; do
    if  ! (git cat-file -p :./$f | jq '.' -S) | cmp -s - <(cat $f | jq '.' -S); then 
        echo $f
    fi
done
```

if you just want to see the diff, do this:

```
for f in `git ls-files *.json`; do
    echo $f
    (git cat-file -p :./$f | jq '.' -S) | diff - <(cat $f | jq '.' -S)
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're like me and you don't actually care about the contents of minimized files (because, y'know, just minimized form of other committed changes), you can do something so that the minimized files don't wrap and take up a hundred lines.

Try running this: `git config --global core.pager 'less -S'`

Then, your minimized file will show up on one line that conveniently disappears off screen.

See also:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6697519/1483861

https://superuser.com/a/272826/454133